# How do you automate data loads in visual studio?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, ssis

I am pretty new to SSIS and SQL in general, and I am still learning the ropes. I am trying to create a few integration packages. First step would be to retrieve the data from one database and load it into another. I've been using the data flow task for this ... However the next step would be to run this package once a daily at a given X time (eg. 1 am). The landing database would be continuously updated , just like the source.

On a seperate package, I'm looking for a way to copy the data from my landing database, and dump it all into another table. This needs to be done so that the package automatically retrieves the rows from the landing database, before it gets overwritten everyday.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi.. please can you outline what have you attempted so far , please see this section as to how best you can ask the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the scheduling of both the created SSIS packages they can be scheduled as SQL Agent job. SQL Agent is part of all SQL Server Editions except Express Edition. For details how to create the automated job to load SSIS packages, please refer to [Schedule SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/sql-server-agent-jobs-for-packages?view=sql-server-2016)